# Unknown Table/Cell padding/margins Affecting Layout

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have no idea how to get rid of the vertical gaps in the table on the "Reports" tab.

http://chicagopcfix.com/skelly

Any help would be extremely welcome.

Answer (score 1):

That's easy.  Don't use tables for non-tabular data.

---

I should probably expound on this... You're using a table to present images and presentational content. You could changing cell spacing and cell padding until you get it just right, but this is a tedious approach to something that could be very easy. Surround your content with div elements (or even better, semantic elements that actually describe your content), and allow them to flow they way they were meant to.  Adjust with margins and positioning if necessary.